# Create option elements from array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to filter the values in `subject` and show them in `option` tags in HTML using Javascript. How can I do that?

```js
var user = [{
  "id": 1,
  "firstname": "kalpit",
  "lastname": "dwivedi",
  "age": 20,
  "hometown": "jhansi",
  "job": "web design",
  "subject": ["Hindi", "English"]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "firstname": "golu",
  "lastname": "gupta",
  "age": 30,
  "hometown": "Vadodara",
  "job": "qa tester",
  "subject": ["Hindi", "Socilogy"]
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "firstname": "john",
  "lastname": "doe",
  "age": 35,
  "hometown": "newport",
  "job": "oprater",
  "subject": ["English", "Socilogy"]
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "firstname": "mohit",
  "lastname": "khare",
  "age": 40,
  "hometown": "kochi",
  "job": "civil",
  "subject": ["infa", "angularjs"]
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please add your relevant code to your question as [mcve]. Then explain what is not working in ***your*** implementation as you intend.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with some of your data... if you wanted dynamically, you would've to do a `$.each` with jquery..

Let me know if this is what you wanted.

```js
var data = '{"id":2, "firstname":"golu", "lastname":"gupta", "age":30, "hometown":"Vadodara", "job":"qa tester", "subject" : ["Hindi", "Socilogy"]}';

    var dataParse = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(dataParse.subject);
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#opt1').html(dataParse.subject[0]);
        $('#opt2').html(dataParse.subject[1]);
    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select name="data" id="data">
        <option value="" id="opt1"></option>
        <option value="" id="opt2"></option>
 </select>
```